# StackOverflowError when making a subclass

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, stack-overflow, subclass

My superclass:

```
public class Node {
    public MyPoint myPoint = new MyPoint();
}
```

My empty subclass:

```
public class MyPoint extends Node {

}
```

The question below was the closest to the problem I could find, however my subclass, in this case, is empty and has no constructors.

[Calling a subclass constructor from a superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109358/calling-a-subclass-constructor-from-a-superclass)

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError
...
at engine.MyPoint.<init>(MyPoint.java:3)
at engine.Node.<init>(Node.java:28)
at engine.MyPoint.<init>(MyPoint.java:3)
at engine.Node.<init>(Node.java:28)
at engine.MyPoint.<init>(MyPoint.java:3)
at engine.Node.<init>(Node.java:28)
...
```

I don't understand why and how there is no recursion as I see it.
How is this

```
public MyPoint myPoint = new MyPoint();
```

Different than this (for example in JavaFX), while creating a new Group doesn't give me the error?

```
public Group group = new Group();
```

Comment: Get rid of the `new MyPoint()` and instead pass in the reference via constructor or method parameter -- problem solved.

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I am going to do that as well, could you please refer to this screenshot I took? I made a whole new project and basically redid exactly the same thing - and now it's working, I have no idea why https://imgur.com/a/KoTrZLu

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Node class absolutely needs a MyPoint field, you have a few options:

- Are you absolutely sure that MyPoint needs to extend from Node? Is it in fact a Node creature? If not, get rid of this, problem solved. If so, then there are other fixes....
- Is MyPoint not unique for each Node instance? If not, make it a static field, problem solved. I doubt this is so, leading us to...
- If MyPoint absolutely needs to extend from Node, **and** needs to be unique for each Node instance, then you must pass the reference in, meaning change this:

```
public class Node {
    public MyPoint myPoint = new MyPoint();
}
```

to this:

```
public class Node {
    public MyPoint myPoint;  // note that MyPoint NOT created here

    public Node(MyPoint myPoint) {
        this.myPoint = myPoint; // but rather passed in HERE
    }
}
```

This way you don't recursively create Node objects each time a Node is created, but rather separate the creation of MyPoint instances from Node instances. Alternatively, this can be also be solved using a setter method.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late answer, I was playing around with what you suggested; I ended up making a setter and calling that setter from another class when needed. Much appreciated, have a good day

Answer (score 5):

`MyPoint` extends `Node`, so when you create an instance of `MyPoint`, you'll first have to initialize its parent `Node`. This means initializing the `myPiont` member and so on until you get a `StackOverflowError`.

There isn't enough context here to suggest changes, but you should probably lose this member.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry but I don't quite understand how I would have to initialize who is its parent: Whenever I create a new **Node** then a new **MyPoint** is created along with it, in the same class, so how does the program not know who is the parent? The parent is automatically the superclass, or did I misunderstand something? This is how you meant it?

Comment: Supply the parent in the constructor.

Comment: A `MyPoint` is a specific type of `Node`. So every time you create a `MyPoint`, it has a `MyPoint` in it, which has a `MyPoint in it, which has a `MyPoint` in it... on until the stack is overflown.

Comment: I see, you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/a/SPSO4d3
I think I'm starting to see how it keeps happening, but still - how do I solve it? Do I need a 3rd class just to spawn a MyPoint from my Node class?